# How to follow a vim golf solution

Tags: vim

To improve my vim skills, I had a look at this vim golf challenge

http://vimgolf.com/challenges/50048db8cdc4060002000004#

Entry #346 was this

```
:%s/.*/"\0",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
```

I entered command mode and type this

```
%s/.*/"\0",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
```

and hit enter

I don't think I did it right because my end file didn't in any way resemble the desired output

My start file looked like this

```
There
is
no
vertical
limit
for
vim
Ninjas
```

The expected end file

```
[ "There", "is", "no", "vertical", "limit", "for", "vim", "Ninjas" ]
```

My end file

```
  1 "There",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
  2 "is",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
  3 "no",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
  4 "vertical",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
  5 "limit",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
  6 "for",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
  7 "vim",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
  8 "Ninjas",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
  9 "",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
```

Comment: I find it very amusing, coming from a vimgolf site, that the "\0" can be replaced with the shorter "&" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%s/.*/"\0",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ`

You have to physically press Enter key and Esc key where you see `<CR>` and `<Esc>`.

Let's break it:

1. `%s/.*/"\0",` will match everything put each word inside `" "` and after each line it will insert `,`
2. `f,C ]` says find (f) first `,` (now cursor on `,`) and delete this and after that enter in insert mode and put `]`. A shortcut for `C ]` is `r]` which will replace current char with `]` and you don't have to press `<Esc>` after that.
3. `ggI[` go to start of file and enter in insert mode and put `[`.
4. `8J` - for next 8 lines make it one line.
5. `ZZ` is equivelent with `:wq`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding your first point, I understand that `.*` matches everything, but what does `\0` do? Is that a backreference to each new line match? how does it work?

Comment: Sure. `\0` means the whole match. Basically it will insert text matched by entire pattern. A backreference is `\1` which will insert text by first backreference. Same for `\2`, `\3` etc.

Comment: Hm, try to read the details section for more information and examples: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace#Details. In my opinion it's a little bit hard to start with vim golf, but no doubt it's a best practice you can get. I struggled myself learning advanced xpath techniques and wished for a xpath golf to exist. Regards

Answer (score 3):

Instead of entering special characters like `<CR>` literally (as 4 different keys), you have to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. This notation is common in Vim parlance, as it's also used for mappings. See `:help key-notation` for details and a full list.

Also, when you see something like `^[`, that's a *control sequence*, in this case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, which is equivalent to <kbd>Esc</kbd>. You can enter those via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> (or whatever it was).

Answer (score 1):

You have to press the keys, so

```
:%s/.*/"\0",<CR>f,C ]<Esc>ggI[ <Esc>8JZZ
```

becomes

```
:%s/.*/"\0",Enterf,C ]EscggI[ Esc8JZZ
```

As in, when you read `<CR>` that means "press the enter key now" and same for `<Esc>`.